# Jest - How to mock RTCPeerConnection?

Tags: unit-testing, mocking, jasmine, jestjs, webrtc

I need to test an ES6 class that initializes a RTCPeerConnection object inside his constructor.
Something like this:

```
export class MyES6Class {
  protected conn: RTCPeerConnection;

  constructor() {
    this.conn = new RTCPeerConnection();
    this.conn.onconnectionstatechange = (event: Event) => this.onConnectionStateChange();
    this.conn.onicecandidate = (event: RTCPeerConnectionIceEvent) => this.onIceCandidate(event);

  ... other stuff...
  }
}
```

When I try to test this class, Jest complains that RTCPeerConnection is not defined.

Now, I've checked Jest documentation [here](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/es6-class-mocks) on how to mock ES6 classes, but it only explains how to mock dependencies that are ES6 classes, while RTCPeerConnection is part of the browser (there is no need to import any module).

So, what is the proper way to mock RTCPeerConnection?

Comment: Generally it's `global.RTCPeerConnection = jest.fn(() => ...)`. Where ... is what you need it to behave like to make tests pass. Could possibly be `= class extends EventTarget {...}` because it's supposed to be event listener and behave like one.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a unit test solution:

`index.ts`:

```js
export class MyES6Class {
  protected conn: RTCPeerConnection;

  constructor() {
    this.conn = new RTCPeerConnection();
    this.conn.onconnectionstatechange = (event: Event) => this.onConnectionStateChange();
    this.conn.onicecandidate = (event: RTCPeerConnectionIceEvent) => this.onIceCandidate(event);
  }

  private onConnectionStateChange() {
    console.log('onConnectionStateChange');
  }

  private onIceCandidate(event: RTCPeerConnectionIceEvent) {
    console.log('onIceCandidate');
  }
}
```

`index.test.ts`:

```js
import { MyES6Class } from './';

describe('63011230', () => {
  it('should pass', () => {
    class TestMyES6Class extends MyES6Class {
      public testonconnectionstatechange(event) {
        this.conn.onconnectionstatechange!(event);
      }
      public testonicecandidate(event: RTCPeerConnectionIceEvent) {
        this.conn.onicecandidate!(event);
      }
    }
    const logSpy = jest.spyOn(console, 'log');
    (global as any).RTCPeerConnection = jest.fn();
    const instance = new TestMyES6Class();
    instance.testonconnectionstatechange({} as Event);
    instance.testonicecandidate({} as RTCPeerConnectionIceEvent);
    expect((global as any).RTCPeerConnection).toBeCalledTimes(1);
    expect(logSpy).toBeCalledWith('onConnectionStateChange');
    expect(logSpy).toBeCalledWith('onIceCandidate');
  });
});
```

unit test result with 100% coverage:

```sh
 PASS  stackoverflow/63011230/index.test.ts (15.4s)
  63011230
    ✓ should pass (23ms)

  console.log
    onConnectionStateChange

      at CustomConsole.<anonymous> (node_modules/jest-environment-enzyme/node_modules/jest-mock/build/index.js:866:25)

  console.log
    onIceCandidate

      at CustomConsole.<anonymous> (node_modules/jest-environment-enzyme/node_modules/jest-mock/build/index.js:866:25)

----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File      | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s 
----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
 index.ts |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        17.405s
```

`jest.config.js`:

```js
module.exports = {
  preset: 'ts-jest/presets/js-with-ts',
  testEnvironment: 'node',
  setupFilesAfterEnv: [
    './jest.setup.js',
  ],
  testMatch: ['**/?(*.)+(spec|test).[jt]s?(x)'],
  verbose: true,
};
```

source code: https://github.com/mrdulin/react-apollo-graphql-starter-kit/tree/master/stackoverflow/63011230

Comment: Hi, Can you help me with this -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71736624/jest-throws-typeerror-cannot-read-properties-of-undefined-reading-getvideotra?noredirect=1#comment126778286_71736624