# Jest throws TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getVideoTracks')

Tags: javascript, typescript, unit-testing, jestjs, ts-jest

I using jest for running my unit test but I am getting an error.

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getVideoTracks')
```

Any suggestions on how to test the below line in jest

```
[videoTrack] = (await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({video: true})).getVideoTracks();
```

My unit test file -

```
import { Track } from './Track';
import { } from '../index';

const mockMediaDevices = {
    getUserMedia: jest.fn()
};

Object.defineProperty(window.navigator, 'mediaDevices', {
    writable: true,
    value: mockMediaDevices,
});

Object.defineProperty(navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia, 'getVideoTracks', {
    writable: true,
    value: jest.fn(),
});

describe('Track', () => {
    describe('applyConstraints()', () => {
        let track: Track;
        let videoTrack: MediaStreamTrack;

        beforeEach(async () => {
            [videoTrack] = (await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ video: true })).getVideoTracks();
            track = new Track(videoTrack as MediaStreamTrack);
        });

        it('should have applyConstraints method', () => {
            expect(typeof track.applyConstraints).toEqual('function');
        });
    });
});
```

Detailed Error -

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getVideoTracks')

      67 |
      68 |     beforeEach(async () => {
    > 69 |       [videoTrack] = (await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({video: true})).getVideoTracks();
         |                                                                                 ^
      70 |       track = new Track(videoTrack as MediaStreamTrack);
      71 |     });
      72 |

      at Object.<anonymous> (Media/Track/Track.test.ts:69:81)
```

I have tried this code -

```
const mockMediaDevices = {
  getUserMedia: jest.fn().mockReturnValue({ getVideoTracks: jest.fn() })
};
Object.defineProperty(navigator, 'mediaDevices', {
  writable: true,
  value: mockMediaDevices,
});
```

But this gives an error -

```
TypeError: undefined is not iterable (cannot read property Symbol(Symbol.iterator))

      73 |
      74 |     beforeEach(async () => {
    > 75 |       [videoTrack] = (await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({video: true})).getVideoTracks();
```

Comment: `getUserMedia: jest.fn().mockReturnValue({ getVideoTracks: jest.fn() })`

Comment: @hoangdv Thanks for comment, `const mockMediaDevices = {
  getUserMedia: jest.fn().mockReturnValue({ getVideoTracks: jest.fn() })
};
Object.defineProperty(window.navigator, 'mediaDevices', {
  writable: true,
  value: mockMediaDevices,
});` I am trying to use this as you suggested, It's giving error - `TypeError: undefined is not iterable (cannot read property Symbol(Symbol.iterator))`

Comment: @hoangdv, Anything yo want to point out..

Comment: [This SO question has the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65112057/jest-spyon-navigator-mediadevices).

Answer (score 0):

Try to mock `mediaDevices` like this

```
Object.defineProperty(global.navigator, 'mediaDevices', {
            configurable: true,
            writable: true,
            value: {
                getUserMedia: jest.fn().mockResolvedValueOnce(mockMediaStreamObject),
            },
        });
```

And for the `getUserMedia` you can mock function with return value where you can implement your version of `getVideoTracks` method.

```
export const mockMediaStreamObject: MediaStream = {
    getVideoTracks(): MediaStreamTrack[] {
        return [];
    },
...
}
```